# Gracefully remove a datasource from VS VB 2008 project?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, datasource

What is the best way to remove a data source you no longer need from a VB2008 project?

Deleting the Data source in the Solution Explorer throws up loads of errors. Deleting tables in the design view of the Dataset designer throws errors. Deleting the Table Adapters at the bottom of the form throws up errors, and now my Toolbox is littered with old data source components in the `<ProjectName>` Components palette.

How do I remove a data source gracefully? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: What sort of errors is it throwing up?

Comment: Many errors in the designer, which then requires me to delete lines from the designer code. Also, all the .Fill methods that get placed into the Form's load sub remain and they error and so on...F5 and repeat till every error line has been removed!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through a bit of reading of all the objects created, and a bit of logical thinking, a satisfactory order I have found is.

1. Delete Binding Source
2. Delete table adapter
3. **DO NOT DELETE TABLE ADAPTER MANAGER** if there are any other data sources.
4. Remove lines of code placed in form Load event
5. Delete schema from Solution Explorer

I still don't know how to remove the extra bits from the Toolbox though. Can anyone help with this bit?